# Laravel site using SPA multiple subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

I want to build a project with 3 section: API, Admin, and User.

I will build the API using Laravel, Admin and User will using ReactJs (SPA) with this route:

1. api.example.com (api)
2. admin.example.com (admin)
3. example.com (user)

I need a solution about project management.

1. Is it better to separate those 3 or should I combine it into one
   project (laravel)?.
2. What about teamwork if I combine or not?
3. Any drawback if I combine or separate those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have overlapping functionalities, I would suggest that you separate the three with three different projects.

The benefits are:

1. One project breakdown will not affect the other
2. You can have separate developers working on different sections and they won't have to worry about conflicts/commits not pertaining to their code
3. It will help you create separate documentation for the three, which will be easier for someone new to the project
4. From a security perspective as well, if one application gets compromised, the others won't be

However these also get influenced by personal experiences, and specific project requirements. Experience is the best teacher.

Comment: Alright. All make sense now. Will separate those 3. Thanks!